# I was trying to delete Ubuntu from my MacBook Air and now I can't access macOS

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, unix

I had installed Ubuntu on my MacBook, but I don't need it anymore so I was trying to delete the parts of Ubuntu.

When I entered Disk Utility the minus button was greyed out, so I checked some videos and they explained that sometimes you just need to change the format of the partitions and the minus button becomes active, but I didn't see any change. Then here on Stack Exchange, I saw that someone reboot his Mac and entered Disk Utility from the Recovery, but when I rebooted my Mac a message appeared: GNU GRUB version 2.06 and now can't see any of my partitions even when I enter to Disk Utility and if I used <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> I only see EFI Boot.

I hope someone could help me, please. Because I'm very concerned and I don't want to lose my information.

`sw_vers` and `diskutil list` output

[image: Diskutil output]

Update
I created a bootable USB with Linux Mint. I used the command `lsblk`and I could see my disks. Now I want to know if I can access my files from here. Or I don't know if I can solve the problem by deleting nvme0nlp3 which is the partition that had Ubuntu.

[image]

Update
`gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`
[image]

Comment: How can you enter Disk Utility if you can not boot to macOS or macOS recovery?

Comment: When I deleted the Ubuntu partition I was using my macOS sesion. But the problem appeard when I was trying to reboot. And I have access to macOS recovery, but I don't see my macOS disk I only see EFI Boot.

Comment: How old is your backup?  It's probably easier to just wipe the drive and reinstall macOS.

Comment: That is Recovery.  You're seeing a bunch of RAM disks used by the installer.

Comment: It would appear the internal drive and/or hardware that supports the internal drive is failing intermittently.

Comment: So my only option is to wipe the drive and reinstall macOS? Is there a way to recover my information?

Comment: I created a bootable USB with Linux Mint. I used the command lsblk and I could see my disks. Now I want to know if I can access my files from here. Or I don't know if I can solve the problem by deleting nvme0nlp3 which is the partition that had Ubuntu

Comment: Deleting a partition will not enable access to another. Is your Mac disk (0n1p2 I assume) encrypted?

Comment: I don't know if is encrypted. How can I know that?

Comment: Can you enter the command `gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` in Linux mint?

Comment: Yes. I posted the outcome of using `gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`

Comment: Do you know which version of macOS is currently installed on your Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes the version of macOS installed on the OP's Mac is Mojave or newer.

The Code `FFFF` shown in the output from `gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` should be `AF0A`. You can change this by running the interactive version of the `gdisk` command. Start by entering the command given below while booted to Linux Mint.

```
gdisk /dev/nvme0n1
```

Next, enter the values given in the Entry column of the table below.

| Entry | Type | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `t` | command | Change a partition's type code |
| `2` | parameter | Partition number |
| `af0a` | parameter | Hex code or GUID |
| `w` | command | Write table to disk and exit |
| `y` | parameter | Do you want to proceed? (Y/N) |

Comment: This works also on macOS High Sierra